# Is there a way to run an sh script every time I plug in my mouse?

Tags: bash, mouse, input, sh

Every time I unplug and plug back in my Razer deathadder essential mouse, I want a certain script to be run (I've already made the script) which just sets up some settings for this mouse. Is there any simple way to do that? Also, I want it to run in the background without a terminal window open. I'm fairly new with this but I've already figured out most of how SH scripts and many commands work but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this. Also, if it matters, I'm actually using Kali but I thought sense it's mostly the same I could post here since it's really a question for both kali and Ubuntu and I'm using xinput for the mouse settings.

edit: I forgot to mention, the exact script I need to run is just

```
xinput set-prop pointer:"Razer Razer DeathAdder Essential" "libinput Accel Speed" -1
```

but I'm probably going to add more settings later.

edit 2: I found a way to do this. with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931244/checking-if-output-of-a-command-contains-a-certain-string-in-a-shell-script) I figured out a method that's probably somewhat inefficient but will work for now. the script for it is

```
#!/bin/bash
zero=0
while [  $zero -lt 1 ]
do

    if "xinput" | grep -q 'Razer Razer DeathAdder Essential Consumer'
    then

        echo "Razer DeathAdder found. Setting libinput Accel Speed to -1"
        xinput set-prop pointer:"Razer Razer DeathAdder Essential" "libinput Accel Speed" -1
        while "xinput" | grep -q 'Razer Razer DeathAdder Essential Consumer'
        do
            sleep 1
        done
    else
        echo "No device found. No commands run."
        until "xinput" | grep -q 'Razer Razer DeathAdder Essential Consumer'
        do
            sleep 1
        done
    fi
done
```

If anybody knows a better method, please share.

Comment: This article might be of assistance. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/how-to-execute-a-shellscript-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device

Comment: @robby1212 Thanks! That did help a lot! I'll look through that and see if i can make a simple script.

Comment: You’re welcome, sorry didn’t have time to write up an answer but did stumble across that link.

Comment: `udev` rule should be used for that.

Comment: @Pilot6 what does that do?

Comment: It runs a script when a device is inserted. You can set a specific device bu its ID.